# Problem in running an executable file in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, executable

I have a simple Python code (3.12 version). It just computes the sum of the ASCII's of a name entered by the user:

```
import sys
args = sys.argv
name=args[1]
print(f"Hello, {name}!")
print("Here is some intelligence that will return a number you will NEVER understand how it is 
 computed :-D \n")
name = name.lower() 
ascii_sum = 0

for char in name:
    if char.isalpha():
        ascii_value = ord(char) 
        ascii_sum += ascii_value

print(ascii_sum)
```

that I have transformed in an executable called `dummy_fct.exe`. Because for some reason I need to be able to call a (Python) executable from an ipynb notebook.

Now, I am trying to call this executable from a new notebook:

```
import subprocess
import sys
name = input("Quel est ton nom ? ")
subprocess.run(["dummy_fct.exe", name], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

But got the following error:

> CompletedProcess(args=['dummy_fct.exe', 'PDH'], returncode=1, stdout='', stderr='[4004] Module object for pyimod02_importers is NULL!\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 22, in \n  File "pathlib.py", line 14, in \n  File "urllib\parse.py", line 40, in \nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipaddress'\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 17, in \nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimod02_importers'\n[4004] Failed to execute script 'pyiboot01_bootstrap' due to unhandled exception!\n')

I do say that I do not understand at all this error message... Can you help me ?

EDIT: The executable was created running these two commands:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script dummy_fct.ipynb
pyinstaller --onefile dummy_fct.py
```

Comment: PyInstaller, going by the traceback

Comment: @0x01010 I updated my question with this information, thanks in advance

Comment: How about `pyinstaller` version?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM 5.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be bug with `pyinstaller`(affecting Python `>=3.11.4`) which is reported [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7692) and it has fixed in `v5.12`. So the [solution is to upgrade the `pyinstaller` version to `>=5.12`](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7692#issuecomment-1582459228).

```
pip install "pyinstaller>=5.12"
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, was not aware of that ! Then, I need to rebuild my executable I guess ?

Comment: Yes, You need to upgrade your `pyinstaller` and rebuild the executable

Comment: Great, that works ! Not easy to guess though ^^